# Saving per-user or per-document preferences in a Photoshop script

Tags: extendscript, photoshop-script

I'm working on a Photoshop script in JavaScript using ExtendScript. My script allows some user input, and I'd like to save it between uses. That is, I'm looking for a way to save a simple string or numeric value under a particular key so that I'll be able to access it on subsequent uses of the script. Simply put, I want to save a preference for my script. How do I do that?

Even better would be to be able to save at least some preferences on a per-document basis. Is that possible? That is, can I store an arbitrary bit of data with a document?

Comment: Maybe https://indisnip.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/storing-custom-data-into-indesign-file-xmp/ applies here as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use put/get custom options to save preference parameters that persist across Photoshop launches:

```js
const kMyFlag = app.stringIDToTypeID( "myFlag" );
const kMyNumber = app.stringIDToTypeID( "myNumber" );
const kMySettings = "mySettings";

function saveSettings()
{
  var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
  desc.putBoolean(kMyFlag, true);
  desc.putInteger(kMyNumber, 42);

  // "true" means setting persists across Photoshop launches.
  app.putCustomOptions( kMySettings, desc, true );
}

function getSettings()
{
  var desc = app.getCustomOptions( kMySettings );
  return [desc.getBoolean( kMyFlag ), desc.getInteger( kMyNumber )];
}
```

Comment: Edited the example to show multiple values on the same descriptor.

Comment: Just in case someone else finds this when looking for a solution that works in indesign: You can use app.insertLabel and app.extractLabel to store your preferences

Comment: Will this solution work on macOS? Based on getCustomOptions documentation "Retrieves user objects from the Photoshop registry for the ID with value key" and since I understand mac does not use registry, hence the question. I dont have a mac so I cant test.

Comment: The "registry" in question is internal to Photoshop, so it'll work on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: noobie question here: is this what `ActionDescriptor` supposed to do? Saving preferences? In Illustrator we have `Preferences` solely for this purpose.

Comment: In Photoshop, `ActionDescriptor` is a generic structure for passing events and related data from scripts to the application. Storing preferences is one use of it, there are many others.

Answer (score 7):

You have some options. You can create a text file and write to it using the `File` object:

```js
var prefs = new File("~/desktop/prefs.txt");
prefs.open("w"); // or "a" to append
prefs.writeln("user:lenny;favorite_color:ff6600;likes:sunsets;");
```

...if you wanted your preferences tied to the script itself.

If you want per-document preferences you could write a string to one of the metadata fields of the file your working on using `Document.info` like this (using the 'instructions' field but you could use any writable field):

```js
var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.info.instructions = "user:lenny;favorite_color:ff6600;likes:sunsets;";
//alert(doc.info.instructions); // see, it works!
```

As for how to actually format the string you could just do it like a simple config file or, if you have a complex user preferences object you could use the `XML` object to construct and serialize it. JSON would be great for this but there is no JSON object in Extendscript, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

For per-document prefs I suggest the use of the XMP Metadata. You can find example snippet here: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/790973. You can leverage AdobeXMPScript library to create your own namespace like it is suggested in the link by Paul Riggott.