# in extendscript - Photoshop, dialog-box persistence?

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript

in extendscript - Photoshop, I would like my dialog-box check boxes to default to previously used choices ... anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices.

**First choice:** Using a `//@targetengine`

Values can be made persistent over a session using a targetengine.

First script

```
//@targetengine myengine
var x = 100;
```

Second script

```
//@targetengine myengine
$.writeln(x);
```

If you close Photoshop all of the values will be lost

**Second choice:** Write to a file.

I wont write an example here. This can be done in so many ways. Plain .txt file. .json file. See [this example](https://github.com/ExtendScript/wiki/wiki/Create-And-Read-Files) on how to read and write files.

Answer (score 0):

fabianmoronzirfas has got the right answer. 
I will say it could with one script only. That script reads in the previous value stored in a text file in a hardcoded location like C:\temp. If the script cannot file the settings file it'll default to some predetermined value and then store this time around.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15960574/1655780  Or see here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/771241

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here is the simple script that saves (and tries to load) your prefs in JSON format to the system temp folder:

```
// set default values
var prefs = {
    file: File(Folder.temp.fsName + "/prefs.json"),
    title: "",
    length: 0
}

// try to load previous prefs
if (prefs.file.exists) prefs = $.evalFile(prefs.file);

// do something
prefs.title = prompt("Type the title:", prefs.title);
prefs.length = prefs.title.length;

// save the prefs to the file
prefs.file.open("w");
prefs.file.write(prefs.toSource());
prefs.file.close();
```

Comment: See also (InDesign): https://stackoverflow.com/a/63220973/14265469